# Jest spy doesn't work in a different directory?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to create some simple unit tests for a small service making web requests and am having a real hard time getting Jest spies to work properly. I've found that the `jest.spyOn` functionality will work, but it depends exactly where the test file is located, which makes no sense to me. So I've got something like this:

**src/getTimetableEventsAsync.js**

```
const getTimetableEventsAsync = async (timetableSecrets, preferredUsername) => {
    console.log(got.get.toString());

    return got.get("someURL").json();
```

**src/getTimetableEventsAsync.unit.test.js** (This works)

```
const got = require('got');
const { getTimetableEventsAsync } = require('./getTimetableEventsAsync');

describe('getTimetableEvents', () => {
    it('Tests the mock', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(got, 'get').mockImplementation(() => {
            console.log('foo');
        });

        await getTimetableEventsAsync('', '');
    });
});
```

**tests/getTimetableEventsAsync.unit.test.js** (This does not works)

```
const got = require('got');
const { getTimetableEventsAsync } = require('../src/getTimetableEventsAsync');

describe('getTimetableEvents', () => {
    it('Tests the mock', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(got, 'get').mockImplementation(() => {
            console.log('foo');
        });

        await getTimetableEventsAsync('', '');
    });
});
```

The thing that is baffling me is that the two test files behave differently. The one that works logs:

```
console.log src/getTimetableEventsAsync.js:11
     function mockConstructor() {
             return fn.apply(this, arguments);
           }
   console.log src/mocks.unit.test.js:7
     foo
```

The one that doesn't work logs:

```
console.log src/getTimetableEventsAsync.js:11
      (url, options) => got(url, { ...options, method })
```

So obviously the `jest.spyOn` isn't working when my test file is within my `tests` directory, but the same code works in my `src` directory fine. `Jest` is always being run at the root and I can have these tests run in the same test run with those different results.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Why can't I get my tests to run in the `tests` directory? I'd ideally like them to run here as it's much simpler to exclude those files from any deployments etc.

So checking within **tests/gettimetableEventsAsync.unit.test.js** to ensure that the spy has worked, reveals that locally within the test it's worked fine, despite immediately after not matching.

```
 console.log tests/getTimetableEventsAsync.unit.test.js:10
      function mockConstructor() {
              return fn.apply(this, arguments);
            }

   console.log src/getTimetableEventsAsync.js:11
      (url, options) => got(url, { ...options, method })
```

Comment: Can you check in tests/getTimetableEventsAsync.unit.test.js that got.get is a spy after spyOn was called? Is there `const got = require('got')` in getTimetableEventsAsync.js? Can you provide a way to replicate the problem? One possible explanation is that `got` isn't the same in src/getTimetableEventsAsync.js and tests/getTimetableEventsAsync.unit.test.js (try to assign both to `global` and check if they are ===). Another one is that spies aren't set as intended. Nothing that was posted can suggest why this could happen.

Comment: @EstusFlask I've added some extra info around the first part. It seems that my `global` is being blanked out between the tests so I can't verify that. I'm just going to try and get a small reproduction.

Comment: @EstusFlask ok, in trying to get a reproduction I've had a moment of revelation. Someone else has set this project up, and within `src` there is a `package.json` which includes `got`. However there's also a `package.json` at the root which doesn't feature `got` (just has CDK stuff). So I'm guessing that's causing some node_modules issues. I'll still try and get a reproduction.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with *got isn't the same*. You can look no further, that's definitely the case. If you need to keep separate `got` in src/node_modules for some reason then import it like `require('../src/node_modules/got')` in order to mock it.

Comment: @EstusFlask do you want to add an answer to that effect so I can accept it.

Comment: Sure. Glad you sorted this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common reason for a spy to not be set when it's set is that it's set on wrong object. If this happens for imported packages, this often means that packages were duplicated in `node_modules` hierarchy.

In this case `got` in *src/getTimetableEventsAsync.js* is not the same object as `got` in *tests/getTimetableEventsAsync.unit.test.js*. As it appears, there's nested project in `src` that has own `node_modules`.

The solution is to either mock proper `got` object in tests:

```
const got = require('../src/node_modules/got');
...
jest.spyOn(got, 'get').mockImplementation(() => {...});
```

Or to deduplicate packages, e.g. remove nested project in `src` or remove duplicate dependencies like `got` from it, so `require('got')` in `src` would import packages from root `node_modules`.